# Set a default value in form only if my user hasrole : ROLE_USER [symfony 4]

Tags: symfony4

I have a reporting request form. I would like the administrator to create a request for a user if needed.

So I have a field that will either be blocked if the user has a certain user role or the field will be opened if the user has an admin role.

DemandType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('applicant', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => User::class,
                'choice_label' => 'username',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
                },
            ))
            ->add('date', DateType::class, array(
                'format' => 'dd MMM yyyy',
                'disabled' => true,
            ))
            ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'Demande de Reporting' => 'Reporting récurrent',
                    'Demande One Shot' => 'Reporting One Shot',
                ),
                'multiple' => false,
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->add('dateDelivery', DateType::class, array(
                'format' => 'dd MMM yyyy',
            ))
            ->add('synthesis', TextareaType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'rows' => '3'
                ),
            ))
        ;
    }
```

DemandController.php

```
    public function create(Request $request, ObjectManager $em, UserRepository $repo)
    {
        $demand = new Demand();

        $users = $repo->findAll();

        $form = $this->createForm(DemandType::class, $demand);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($demand);
            $em->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Demande bien enregistrée');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('demand_show', array(
                'slug' => $demand->getSlug(),
            ));

        } elseif ($form->isSubmitted() && !$form->isValid()) {
            $this->addFlash('danger', 'Erreur lors de la validation du formulaire');
        }

        return $this->render('demand/new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'users' => $users
        ));
    }
```

newDemand.html.twig

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        {{ form_label(form.applicant, 'Demandeur * :', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-4 col-form-label'}}) }}
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ form_widget (form.applicant, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        {{ form_label(form.applicant, 'Demandeur * :', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-4 col-form-label'}}) }}
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ form_widget (form.applicant, {'attr': {'value':app.user.username, 'disabled':'disabled', 'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

I would like, if user have `ROLE_USER` the fields applicant was disable and show the name of user and if the user have `ROLE_ADMIN` the fields show all user available in database. for this second parts it's ok an admin can attribute a demand to an other user.

Now i would like to force a value `app.user.username` in widget `demand.applicant` for user with `ROLE_USER`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: introduce a new option in DemandType like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title');
    if($options['is_admin']){
        $builder->add('applicant', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => User::class,
            'choice_label' => 'username',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
            },
        ))
    }
    $builder->add('date', DateType::class, array(
            'format' => 'dd MMM yyyy',
            'disabled' => true,
        ))
        ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Demande de Reporting' => 'Reporting récurrent',
                'Demande One Shot' => 'Reporting One Shot',
            ),
            'multiple' => false,
            'required' => true,
        ))
        ->add('dateDelivery', DateType::class, array(
            'format' => 'dd MMM yyyy',
        ))
        ->add('synthesis', TextareaType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
                'rows' => '3'
            ),
        ))
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                //add this param to the rest if you have this block already
                'is_admin' => false
            ]
        );
    }
```

Then in cotroller you are able to pass the admin flag to DemandType:

```
public function create(Request $request, ObjectManager $em, UserRepository $repo)
{
    $demand = new Demand();

    $users = $repo->findAll();
    //Change here
    $form = $this->createForm(DemandType::class, $demand, ['is_admin' => $this->isGranted('ROLE'ADMIN')]);
    //Change end
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        //Change here
        if(!$this->isGranted('ROLE'ADMIN')){
            $demand->setApplicant($this->getUser());
        }
        //Change end
        $em->persist($demand);
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Demande bien enregistrée');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('demand_show', array(
            'slug' => $demand->getSlug(),
        ));

    } elseif ($form->isSubmitted() && !$form->isValid()) {
        $this->addFlash('danger', 'Erreur lors de la validation du formulaire');
    }

    return $this->render('demand/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'users' => $users
    ));
}
```

Twig:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        {{ form_label(form.applicant, 'Demandeur * :', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-4 col-form-label'}}) }}
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ form_widget (form.applicant, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Demandeur</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{app.user.username}}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Good answer. It would probably pass `$this->getUser()` as a `user` option to the form and set the default-value for `applicant` in the `buildForm` method instead of in the controller to keep things separated. +1 :)

Comment: I had this approach in my mind, but I prefer to abandon the EntityType in DemandType when the user should not see an option list. Default value means the user itself is preselected but can still change, as I understand this should not be possible. And why load all users from database when there is no need to select one?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me maybe. I agree with you that removing the `EntityType` field from the form for `ROLE_USER` is a good idea. I was just saying that the logic of setting the default-value to the current user should be moved to the `FormType`. That's why I'd pass the `User` object to the form-type instead of just the role-name or a bool. The `applicant` field  can be omitted if set by a form-event subscriber pre-validation instead of in the controller. Regardless of encapsulation - setting the user after validation prevents the chance to validate if `applicant` is a valid user here.

Comment: Long story short: I mean that you need to allow `null` as a value for `applicant` in the validator-configuration  - which might not be desired - with your approach.

Comment: @Rawburner, it s good question, I dont think about, and it s really simple like that. I dont show the field if it's a user and i show and load all users for admin. Perfect For me. Thx a lot

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich I understand what you mean and I see it would be cleaner. I think azrik is able to refactor the code in a way it fitts best in his project.